# Displaying BBOX hash in URL

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I think I'm doing something wrong in the variables or syntax... i don't know, help me to correct my code. (I'm using Leaflet for the map show)

**Desired Behavior**

The user should be able to see the BBOX entering the coordinates into the URL, for example:

> .com/#013.0,052.0,013.5,052.5

I only care that the BBOX is shown, I don't care that the URL coordinates change when zooming or moving around the map.

**My HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
      crossorigin=""
    />

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="leaflet-hash.js"></script>

    <script>
      var map = L.map("map").setView([42, 12], 4);
      // var hash = new L.hash(map);

      var urlhash = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("/");
      var boundingBox = "";

      L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        maxZoom: 22,
        minZoom: 1,
        continuousWorld: false,
        noWrap: false,
        attribution:
          'Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.',
        detectRetina: false,
      }).addTo(map);

      var bboxField = L.control({
        position: "bottomleft",
      });

      bboxField.onAdd = function (map) {
        //create div container for control
        var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "myButtonBar");
        //prevent mouse events from propagating through to the map
        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
        //create custom radio buttons
        div.innerHTML =
          'BBOX (Left (LON) ,Bottom (LAT), Right (LON), Top (LAT), comma separated, with or without decimal point):<br><input type="text" id="bbox_field"/><button id="setDimensions">Display BBOX</button><button id="remove">Remove</button>';

        return div;
      };

      bboxField.addTo(map);
      $(".myButtonBar").css("font-weight", "bold");
      if (urlhash[0] !== "") {
        $("#bbox_field").val(urlhash[0]);

        draw_bbox(urlhash[0]);
      }

      function draw_bbox(box) {
        var myarray = box.split(",");
        var bounds = [
          [myarray[1], myarray[0]],
          [myarray[3], myarray[2]],
        ];

        boundingBox = L.rectangle(bounds, { color: "#ff7800", weight: 1 });
        map.removeLayer(boundingBox);
        boundingBox.addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(boundingBox.getBounds());
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
      }

      $("#setDimensions").click(function () {
        draw_bbox($("#bbox_field").val());
      });

      $("#bbox_field").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          $("#setDimensions").click();
        }
      });

      // console.log(bbox)
      $("#remove").click(function () {
        map.removeLayer(boundingBox);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Leaflet Hash Plugin Code**

```
(function(window) {
    var HAS_HASHCHANGE = (function() {
        var doc_mode = window.documentMode;
        return ('onhashchange' in window) &&
            (doc_mode === undefined || doc_mode > 7);
    })();

    L.hash = function(map) {
        this.onHashChange = L.Util.bind(this.onHashChange, this);

        if (map) {
            this.init(map);
        }
    };

    L.hash.parseHash = function(hash) {
        if(hash.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            hash = hash.substr(1);
        }
        var args = hash.split("/");
        if (args.length == 3) {
            var zoom = parseInt(args[0], 10),
            lat = parseFloat(args[1]),
            lon = parseFloat(args[2]);
            if (isNaN(zoom) || isNaN(lat) || isNaN(lon)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return {
                    center: new L.LatLng(lat, lon),
                    zoom: zoom
                };
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    L.hash.formatHash = function(map) {
        var center = map.getCenter(),
            zoom = map.getZoom(),
            precision = Math.max(0, Math.ceil(Math.log(zoom) / Math.LN2));

        return "#" + [zoom,
            center.lat.toFixed(precision),
            center.lng.toFixed(precision)
        ].join("/");
    },

    L.hash.prototype = {
        map: null,
        lastHash: null,

        parseHash: L.hash.parseHash,
        formatHash: L.hash.formatHash,

        init: function(map) {
            this.map = map;

            // reset the hash
            this.lastHash = null;
            this.onHashChange();

            if (!this.isListening) {
                this.startListening();
            }
        },

        removeFrom: function(map) {
            if (this.changeTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(this.changeTimeout);
            }

            if (this.isListening) {
                this.stopListening();
            }

            this.map = null;
        },

        onMapMove: function() {
            // bail if we're moving the map (updating from a hash),
            // or if the map is not yet loaded

            if (this.movingMap || !this.map._loaded) {
                return false;
            }

            var hash = this.formatHash(this.map);
            if (this.lastHash != hash) {
                location.replace(hash);
                this.lastHash = hash;
            }
        },

        movingMap: false,
        update: function() {
            var hash = location.hash;
            if (hash === this.lastHash) {
                return;
            }
            var parsed = this.parseHash(hash);
            if (parsed) {
                this.movingMap = true;

                this.map.setView(parsed.center, parsed.zoom);

                this.movingMap = false;
            } else {
                this.onMapMove(this.map);
            }
        },

        // defer hash change updates every 100ms
        changeDefer: 100,
        changeTimeout: null,
        onHashChange: function() {
            // throttle calls to update() so that they only happen every
            // `changeDefer` ms
            if (!this.changeTimeout) {
                var that = this;
                this.changeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    that.update();
                    that.changeTimeout = null;
                }, this.changeDefer);
            }
        },

        isListening: false,
        hashChangeInterval: null,
        startListening: function() {
            this.map.on("moveend", this.onMapMove, this);

            if (HAS_HASHCHANGE) {
                L.DomEvent.addListener(window, "hashchange", this.onHashChange);
            } else {
                clearInterval(this.hashChangeInterval);
                this.hashChangeInterval = setInterval(this.onHashChange, 50);
            }
            this.isListening = true;
        },

        stopListening: function() {
            this.map.off("moveend", this.onMapMove, this);

            if (HAS_HASHCHANGE) {
                L.DomEvent.removeListener(window, "hashchange", this.onHashChange);
            } else {
                clearInterval(this.hashChangeInterval);
            }
            this.isListening = false;
        }
    };
    L.hash = function(map) {
        return new L.hash(map);
    };
    L.map.prototype.addHash = function() {
        this._hash = L.hash(this);
    };
    L.map.prototype.removeHash = function() {
        this._hash.removeFrom();
    };
})(window);
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Have you tried setting breakpoints inside the `draw_bbox` function?